# Append a various text after the closing bracket

Tags: regex

I have below code, and using IntelliJ ,find and replacement. I want to append **.driver** to it

Current code:

```
click(page.username)
click(page.password)
```

Expected code:

```
click(page.username,driver)
click(page.password,driver)
```

Note- after click(, the text has different values.

Comment: Find: `)`, replace: `,driver)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open find and replace panel in InteliJ.
Find text )
replace text ,driver)

Replace one by one in case you have other ) characters. Click on exclude to ignore and replace to replace text.

Comment: Anyway to click(page.username match this too  when replacing ? I only wan to replace which has click events .

Comment: You can selectively do that in InteliJ. Just exclude places that you don't want to replace